# How can I use my host, a regular dream host acct as a node server?

Tags: node.js

I've tried some methods online using ssh but can't figure it out. why is it so difficult to install when it's basically just Javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A regular Dreamhost account will not allow a long running process which a node server is.  You will need a VPS account.

Also, the node application and V8 engine inside it is not just javascript.  It's an actual native application.  Your scripts are "just javascript", but the infrastructure that makes the node server run is native code.

Comment: That sucks but Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 5):

In 2015, Dreamhost started to support the deployment of nodejs (as well as ruby, python) applications through the [Passenger domain option](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3A-Node.js-tutorial). For more information on Passenger, check [Node.js with Passenger tutorial](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3A-Node.js-tutorial).

Unfortunately, this is available only on VPS running Unbuntu.

Note that on the Dreamhost wiki, under [Nodejs](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Node.js), they write

> DreamHost does not support node.js on shared web servers, as the security setup on DreamHost shared servers is incompatible with compiling or running node.js. If you try to compile node.js on one of the shared web servers, your user will automatically be banned through grsec (taking down all the php websites that run under that user) and the server will have to be rebooted before your user can be unbanned. If you do it one more time, you will be forced to move to a VPS.